# Mysql multi count in one query

Tags: mysql, sql, aggregate-functions

How can I count records for two columns in one table using different query criteria?

Table looks like:

```
   user_id  |   date     | status
------------------------------
      1     | 2011-01-02 |   1
      2     | 2011-01-03 |   1
      3     | 2011-01-02 |   0
      4     | 2011-01-03 |   1
      1     | 2011-01-02 |   1
```

I want to count two values in one query. The first one is number of user_id group by status and the second is count of user_id group by date.

How can I do that?

Comment: use something like SELECT COUNT ...

Comment: Please provide an example of your expected output, because the counts per status have no relation to the counts per date.  A cartesian product is the only result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't have different GROUP BY clauses in the same query -- each count will have to be in an independent query.

But you can return the output in a single query/resultset using subselects (subquery in the SELECT clause):

```
   SELECT COUNT(a.user_id) AS numUsersPerStatus,
          (SELECT COUNT(b.user_id)
             FROM YOUR_TABLE b
         GROUP BY b.date) AS numUsersPerDate
    FROM YOUR_TABLE a
GROUP BY a.status
```

Comment: If a sub query is used in Select Column, it should only return 1 row and 1 column, numUsersPerDate will return multiple rows each for different date? i think this query can give runtime error based on data? please correct me if i am wrong .....

Comment: @Nitin Midha: No, this will not result in a runtime error.  The numUsersPerDate will be duplicated for each status count - The result will be a cartesian product.

Comment: Then i hope, it should be in from clause with a cross join .... It is something known difference between SQL Server and MySQL? As far as i remem, in SQL Server it will give an error ...

Comment: @Nitin Midha: `CROSS JOIN` is just ANSI-92 syntax for producing a cartesian product.  And no, the query provided would not produce an error on SQL Server either - subselects are very common, because ANSI-89 didn't support OUTER joins (this example would be re-written with a LEFT JOIN, if there were criteria to link the tables).

Answer (score 0):

You **don't**.

You should use two queries. There's no advantage to doing this with a single query.

If you *really* want to do it you can try this:

```
SELECT 'date' AS grptype, date AS grp, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY date
UNION ALL
SELECT 'status' AS grptype, status AS grp, COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS cnt
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY status
```

Result:

```
grptype    grp         cnt
date       2011-01-02  2  
date       2011-01-03  2  
status     0           1  
status     1           3
```

However I would *strongly* advise against doing this. You want two different and unrelated result sets so you should use two separate queries.

Comment: The UNION as-is won't work - date and status columns are different data types.  And you'd want to use this as derived table/inline view for ultimately using MAX to condense into fewer rows.

Comment: why would you advise against doing that?

Comment: @rahmanisback: Because it is an abuse of SQL. Every time you mix data types in a single column a unicorn dies. In most databases things like this wouldn't even be allowed. MySQL allows it due to type conversions. But just because you *can* doesn't mean you *should*.